# SciFi Movie - Paralyzed man power suit - full recovery (VHS, 90's?)

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a post apocalyptic movie in which the character is a disabled teacher in a wheelchair. He loves one woman, so he goes to test therapy which is supposed to make him fully functional.

Then company that is providing therapy puts him in a sort of coffin with green goo in it. In order to walk he gets armour but he cannot breathe outside of it.

At the end he kills himself.

Comment: It seems that it is it :) Thanks!